# NX Client (win) fonts not rendering after Ubuntu Upgrade

Tags: 12.10, windows, nx

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.10 and No Machine NX Server (3) etc. I've gone home, and have discovered that the windows nx client (3.5) will not display fonts for graphical applications.

The same client works fine connecting to Ubuntu 12.04

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks joeforker - the magic setting on the "Use Custom Settings" panel was to check the "Disable the render extension"

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get the fonts to show up in GTK applications by going into the NX client's "Use custom settings" panel and checking "Disable..." for all the "Performance" checkboxes. Qt applications work fine either way.

Comment: Watch out doing these changes : it seems that suspended sessions are no more available when changing such settings. So plan to close current sessions and restart new ones .

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.
Changing the client to OpenNX:s client solved the problem for me.
I've been running it for a couple of days  now and it works like a charm. 
http://opennx.net/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Not working for me - at the moment I'm using putty and Xming to get around the issue - Xming starts up when I try OpenNX. Also, I prefer not having a desktop, and OpenNX does not seem to support the "custom" unix view.